# how to filter those objects with match parameter in list element using underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

```
nodedatasource = [
    {"id":1,'name':'a'},
    {"id":2,'name':'b'},
    {"id":3,'name':'c'},
    {"id":4,'name':'d'},
]
list_ids = [3,2] #
```

I want to get a filtered datasource objects list having id in list_ids?
I tried with this approach.

....which need some correction

```
datanode =_.filter(nodedatasource, function(element,ids){
    return element.id in ids
})
```

Comment: `datanode = datasource.filter(({ id }) => list_ids.includes(id));`. You don't need an external library for that

Comment: yes, yours correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just wanna do this in pure JavaScript

```js
var datasource = [{"id":1,'name':'a'},
              {"id":2,'name':'b'},
              {"id":3,'name':'c'},
              {"id":4,'name':'d'},
            ]
var list_ids = [3,2]

var filteredArray = datasource.filter(elem => list_ids.includes(elem.id));

console.log(filteredArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const list_ids = [3, 2]
const datanode =_.filter(nodedatasource,function(element){
                return list_ids.includes( element.id )
        })
//datanode = [{"id":2,'name':'b'},
//            {"id":3,'name':'c'}]
```

Comment: which is more bettter yours or this one :                                                                     datanode = _.filter(nodedatasource,function(element,ids){
                    return _.contains(list_ids,element.id)
                });

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to do it completely in underscorejs it :

```
list_ids = [3, 2]
datanode = _.filter(nodedatasource,function(element,list_ids){ 
              return _.contains(list_ids,element.id) 
             });
//datanode = [{"id":2,'name':'b'},
//            {"id":3,'name':'c'}]
```